# Request Entity Too Large on insertAll

Tags: google-bigquery

When running an `insertAll` post, sometimes we get `Request Entity Too Large` and this is a HTML response,

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Request Entity Too Large</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Request Entity Too Large</H1>
<H2>Error 413</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

- Which limit we are crossing?
- Why is this a HTML response and not JSON/XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#quota:

- Maximum row size: 20 KB
- Maximum data size of all rows, per insert: 1 MB

This for streaming inserts. If you need to insert bigger rows, use the batch method.

Comment: Are you sure that data size of all rows is 1MB, it works fine even with 10MB or 20MB.

Comment: @felipe-hoffa is there an example for the batch method? I've got a `RowIterator` object for the rows I want to insert